# Problem clicking on link in header in selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, header

Hello I have an issue clicking on the link "Assortiment"
on this page: https://www.colruyt.be/fr

In order to click it I use :

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//li[@class = "first leaf menu-mlid-9143"]')
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two elements that can be found with that xpath. The first one is hidden in the side pullout menu for the mobile version and the second is the one you want. Try scoping your xpath to the `div` with `main-navigation` class.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class = "main-navigation"]//li[@class = "first leaf menu-mlid-9143"]')
```